# How can I return the content of a variable by using match and regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, telegram, telegraf

I want to be able to return the content of these variables by using regular expressions.

```
'use strict'

const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const fs = require('fs')

var ar1 = fs.readFileSync('folder/ar1.txt').toString()
var ar2 = fs.readFileSync('folder/ar2.txt').toString()
var ar3 = fs.readFileSync('folder/ar3.txt').toString()
```

I tried using:

```
app.hears(/\bar\d/i, (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply(ctx.match[0])
    //Returns: "ar1"
})
```

But this only returns the string, not the content of the variable.

Comment: Did you try `match[1]`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use `eval` here, but I don't suggest it. Instead, I suggest you map your variables.

```
const files = {
    "ar1" : fs.readFileSync('folder/ar1.txt').toString(),
    "ar2" : fs.readFileSync('folder/ar2.txt').toString(),
    "ar3" : fs.readFileSync('folder/ar3.txt').toString()
};
```

Then, you can use your found string to reply with your object key (a `Map` can also be used here)

```
app.hears(/\b(a+)r\d/i, (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply(files[ctx.match[0]]);
    //now returns the file
});
```